# By store (number), list the maximum number of store visits made by a customer

Tags: sql, teradata, store

The three tables that I'm linking are item_scan_fact, member_dimension and store_dimension. So far this is what I have:

```
SELECT 
    store_dimension.store_number, 
    member_dimension.member_number  
    COUNT (item_scan_fact.visit_number) AS NumVisits 
FROM 
    member_dimension, 
    item_scan_fact 
    INNER JOIN store_dimension
        ON item_scan_fact.member_key = member_dimension.member_key
       AND item_scan_fact.store_key = store_dimension.store_key 
GROUP BY 
    store_dimension.store_number, 
    member_dimension.member_number, NumVisits;
```

Comment: is this query returning the correct result ? if not, please describe on the issue you meet

Answer (score 1):

On the surface it appears solvable with a couple [Common Table Expressions](https://community.teradata.com/t5/Database/Common-Table-Expressions-CTE/td-p/58803)

Does this help point you in the right direction?

```
WITH s1 -- JJAUSSI: Find the visit_number_count by member_key and store_key
AS
(SELECT isf.member_key
       ,isf.store_key
       -- JJAUSSI: DISTINCT resolves a potential 1:N (one to many) relationship here
       ,COUNT( DISTINCT isf.visit_number) AS visit_number_count 
   FROM item_scan_fact isf
  GROUP BY isf.member_key
          ,isf.store_key),
s2 -- JJAUSSI: Find the visit_number_count_max by member_key
AS
(SELECT s1.member_key
       ,MAX(s1.visit_number_count) AS visit_number_count_max
  FROM s1
 GROUP BY s1.member_key)
-- JJAUSSI: Use this version to see the list of store_key values 
-- that have the visit_number_count_max value. This has the potential
-- to be a 1:N relationship.
SELECT s1.member_key
      ,md.member_number 
      ,s1.store_key
      ,sd.store_number
      ,s1.visit_number_count
  FROM s2 INNER JOIN s1
             ON s2.member_key = s1.member_key
            AND s2.visit_number_count_max = s1.visit_number_count
          INNER JOIN store_dimension sd
             ON sd.store_key = s1.store_key
          INNER JOIN member_dimension md
             ON md.member_key = s1.member_key;
```

If this is what you were going for...congratulations! On to the next query!

If you ultimately are after a *single* store_key response for each member_key (basically you want to determine the member_key's "primary" store_key) then an additional step is probably needed (depending on your data).

Here are some ideas:

1. Evaluate the member_key based on some other summable facet of
   item_scan_fact (like total price paid?)
2. If you consider all store_key values of equal merit that have the same visit_number_count_max value for a given member_key, just choose a store_key with MAX or MIN

Answer (score 0):

You would seem to want:

```
SELECT member_number, MAX(NumVisits)
FROM (SELECT sd.store_number, md.member_number  
             COUNT(*) AS NumVisits 
      FROM member_dimension md JOIN
           item_scan_fact isf
           ON md.member_key = isf.member_key JOIN
           store_dimension sd
           ON isf.store_key = sd. store_key 
      GROUP BY sd.store_number, md.member_number
     ) sm
GROUP BY member_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return both the max and the matching customer number you can apply a Teradata SQL extension, `qualify`:

```
SELECT sd.store_number, md.member_number  
       COUNT(*) AS NumVisits 
FROM member_dimension md JOIN
     item_scan_fact isf
     ON md.member_key = isf.member_key JOIN
     store_dimension sd
     ON isf.store_key = sd. store_key 
GROUP BY sd.store_number, md.member_number
QUALIFY
   rank() -- might return multiple rows with the same max, ROW_NUMBER a single row
   over (partition by sd.store_number 
        order by NumVisits desc) = 1
```